# Generating filebeat custom fields

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, custom-fields, filebeat

I have an elasticsearch cluster (ELK) and some nodes sending logs to the logstash using filebeat. All the servers in my environment are CentOS 6.5.

The filebeat.yml file in each server is enforced by a Puppet module (both my production and test servers got the same configuration).

I want to have a field in each document which tells if it came from a production/test server.

I wanted to generate a dynamic custom field in every document which indicates the environment (production/test) using filebeat.yml file.

In order to work this out i thought of running a command which returns the environment (it is possible to know the environment throught facter) and add it under an "environment" custom field in the filebeat.yml file but I couldn't find any way of doing so.

Is it possible to run a command through filebeat.yml? 
Is there any other way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your filebeat.yml:

```
filebeat:
  prospectors:
    -
      paths:
        - /path/to/my/folder
      input_type: log

      # Optional additional fields. These field can be freely picked
      # to add additional information to the crawled log files
      fields:
        mycustomvar: production
```

Answer (score 3):

in filebeat-7.2.0 i use next syntax:

```
processors:
- add_fields:
    target: ''
    fields:
      mycustomfieldname: customfieldvalue
```

note: target = '' means that mycustomfieldname is a top-level field
[official 7.2 docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.2/add-fields.html)

Comment: Is it possible to assign a field type to the custom fields here as well? For example, can you make "mycustomfieldname" a "text" or "keyword" type in this file alone?

Comment: Documentation has nothing about this. Type you can specify by mapping in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can add fields to the document through filebeats.

The [official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-filebeat-options.html#configuration-fields) shows you how.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply but what I need is a dynamic field that will specify the server's environment. I know I can add a custom field but I need it to be a command. The reason I don't want to do it manually like you suggested is that I have many servers and I don't want to create a different file for each and everyone of them.  Thanks anyway!!

Comment: Put the variable in there from your configuration management system when you deploy the filebeat config to the server.

Comment: I guess I will do that, I wanted to know if there is another option. Thanks a lot :)